# Trying to determine how a success call of an async function can be monitored or appended to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that calls an async function.  My examples use ajax, but it is really anything that is async.

I am trying to add additiional information in the success of the ajax call.

Order of what occurs:

-my function is called with a param being an $.ajax call.

-my function needs to add 1 line of code to the $.ajax.success call

my code is something like the following:

```
function myFunct(settings, callback){
   if(!callback)return;
   var x = 100;
   //here is where i have issues, as i want 
   //to be able to adjust the success function
   // to also have 1 line of code, a decrementer.
   //I want to do something like settings.success = "x--;" + settings.success;

   callback(settings);

   //I also wasnt sure if you could wrap 'callback' 
   //with a success function when the inner success function executes
}
```

sample call:

```
 var settings = "";//settings of the ajax call.
 myFunct(settings, function(x){ $.ajax(x);});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make sure that callback always returns a promise object, you can use `.done()`

```
function myFunct( settings, callback ) {
    if (!callback) return;
    var x = 100;

    callback(settings).done(function(){
        x--;
    });
}
var settings = { url: "foobar.php" };
myFunct( settings, function(x) {
    return $.ajax(x);
})
```

Just to be sure, `var x = 100` is just an example right? as it stands now, it would go out of scope and is pointless.

Comment: As a side question:  is settings is an array of params for AJAX in this case... How would i go about having settings contain things like "success: function(){...},"  because as of right now, that seems like it might be throwing an error.  Would i just JSON.stringift it all?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, can you give an example? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You shouldn't need to stringify it at all, if you are passing it directly into callback and then callback passes it directly to $.ajax

Comment: what if it is an array of "settings"  Same thing?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QdyVK/1/ that part would have to be handled by the callback.

Comment: sweet.  I kept thinking there would be issues when settings contains additional anonymous functions like success: fucntion(), error: function() etc.

Comment: Yes, i just left those out to keep it simple, they'll work no problem.